# How to display block or trigger the style on Woocommerce if !is_in_stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display a block or DIV when the product is out of stock but the condition does not appear to work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'display_welcome', 10);
function display_welcome() {
global $_product;
 if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
    ?>
         <style>
            #hello {display:block }
         </style>
<?    
     }
      }
```

html

```
 <div id="hello">Try this product instead</div>
```

Comment: add .my-customclass class in CSS and copy pase my anser. Its simple

Comment: thanks I revised my question, what I would like to happen is display a block or div or add a class to that div which has a display block css not add class to availability

Comment: the updated answer will help you

Comment: thanks however I would need to add the div id hello to an existing div not create a new div

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_get_availability', 'display_welcome', 10, 2);

function display_welcome($availability_class, $_product) {

    if ($availability_class['availability'] == 'Out of stock') {
        $availability_class['class'] = $availability_class['class'] . ' my-customclass';
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hooks_add_div', 33);

        function hooks_add_div() {
            echo '<div id="helllo">mujeebu rahman</div>';
        }

    }
}
```